# Exclude Script files from loading w/ Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, devtools

I have a migrated SharePoint application that brought over a bunch of old JavaScript files. One of these files is causing errors in the new environment but I'm unsure of the culprit. They aren't throwing console errors, but rather modifying elements by adding unwanted attributes and classes

Is there a way to prevent the loading of individual .js files without modifying the source? I know blackboxing will prevent the debugger from stepping into the code, but it still loads. If I can narrow it down to one file, I can fix the conflicts that are occurring

Comment: TBH it'd probably be easier to just comment that `<script>` tag out (or remove it from the list used to generates said tag in case it's automatic).

Comment: Probably some sort of JavaScipt filtering plugin would work.  Something like uMatrix or NoScript, although I'm not sure if NoScript will let you block individual files, but instead only filters domains.  I'm not sure about uMatrix.

Comment: Just a thought, but an AdBlocker is usually capable of blocking explicit URLs...

Comment: Unfortunately, the source is in a third party control which I cannot modify @DJDavid98..

Comment: @Siguza I found a post that supports your suggestion but that option doesn't seem to be available in AdBlock anymore :(

Comment: @Colbs Well, AdBlock Plus can certainly do it... just tried it in Chrome, Firefox and Safari. Just block `example.com/path/to/your.js`, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Indeed that did it. Thanks a lot @Siguza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, posting this as an answer:

Although intended for other uses, [AdBlock Plus](https://adblockplus.org/) can do what you're asking, and it's available for all major browsers.
Just set up a filter like `example.com/path/to/your.js` and that script should no longer get loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is using Fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler). It allows you to isolate particular js files and either force them not load, or it allows you to inject your own local JavaScript files on the fly. This way you don't have to migrate your project/solution locally for testing, you can continue to run this on your sharepoint server, and use your own local JS files..

Good luck!!

Answer (score 1):

For the record, this can now be done directly in Chrome Devtools as of version 59.

Load the page, open devtools, then click the network tab. Find the request you'd like to block, right click on it, then select "Block request URL" & reload the page. That resource will be blocked this time around.

Very useful!

Comment: Yes! This is very useful indeed, I just blocked several image requests on this page